# What standards apply when specifying coating/painting in a mechanical part drawing?

Tags: drafting, standards, technical-drawing

I have produced a part drawing which calls up a machined mark on a flat surface, and the supplier has manufactured the part with this surface painted. I haven't added a note to the drawing that says that machined surfaces are not to be painted. Can I ask for the part to be re-worked by the supplier based on a generic 'drawing to BS 8888' note in the drawing border?

Comment: Yes you can specify different coating options for specified areas by drawing a dot dash line ofset on the outer side of your surface or around the area if the area is visible towards you in the ISO standard. But your question is neglecting to tell if you are in US or not

Comment: Does BS 8888 say that machined surfaces are not to be painted?

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I am not in the UK, so working to BS/ISO standards. BS 8888 does not explicitly say that machined surfaces can't be painted, but it does reference tons of standards (which I do not have access to) that are more specific. I was hoping one of them had a directive.

Comment: I suppose in future I will add paint notes as suggested by joojaa above